# Not able to position Bootstrap/popper dropdown menu to the right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am learning to use css grid to make layout and use components from bootstrap. To begin with, I just want to be able to make a responsive drop down to the right corner. but it's not working. I know its a very primitive question, but still not able to get it done. I know there would be many ways to do it. I would like to get to know a generic way using which I can accomplish many other things as well.
Code is:

index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Bootstrap
    </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">
  <ul>
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="mydiv" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css is

```
.container {
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 900px;
}
```

Edit:
Actually right now my purpose is to learn CSS grid out of interest. I have heard that many things can be accomplished by float,flexbox etc, but since I am new, I don't want to learn too many things, I just want to learn CSS Grid so well that I can accomplish even basic things using this quickly. And using dropdown from bootstrap library was just a quick way to get dropdown code to learn CSS grid concept to apply on

Comment: Regarding your edit - as I mentioned in my comment below, that is a different question to the one you first asked, so that means it should be posted as a new question - each question on Stack Overflow should be about one single problem. Also, when you do post your new question, make sure you include your code for the CSS grid this time so we know what you are asking about! :) Also, keep in mind that questions usually get downvoted and even closed if they don't have relevant code that shows some effort into trying it yourself, so take a look through the Bootstrap docs & give it a go! :)

Comment: The [Bootstrap Grid documentation here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) is actually pretty easy to follow and has lots of examples, so its a good place to start!

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thanks a lot for your guidance. Will keep in mind and check out this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

1. [**Bootstrap have a class for this**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment)  `dropdown-menu-right`, so just just need add this to your dropdown div: `<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">`
2. Align the contents of `#mydiv` to the right so that the "Dropdown" label appears on the right: `#mydiv { text-align:right; }`

**Working snippet** to see it in action (note I've also added `list-style:none;` to the `<ul>` to remove the bullet from before the dropdown):

```css
li.nav-item.dropdown{
    text-align:right;
    list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="mydiv">
  <ul>
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="mydiv" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: the "mydiv" tag in this example is global, and moving it to the right is globally illogical.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov That should have bee mentioned in your question  then:)  That's easy to fix - just move the alignment to the list  (see updated answer)

Comment: @FluffyKitten : For my understanding, shouldn't dropdown-menu-right class be part of  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="mydiv" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a> because that is the dropdown header...i guess my basics are shaky here.. What is the purpose of <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

Comment: @FluffyKitten also I have heard that one can accomplish a lot using css grid in layout etc..isn't there a way to get it done with some quick css grid feature without using bootstrap class.

Comment: `<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">` is the correct way to do it according to the Bootstrap documentation - [see the link to the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment). When you are already using a Bootstrap dropdown and Bootstrap provide a right-aligned menu by adding a single `dropdown-menu-right` class to the menu, I'm not sure why you would want to start adding in extra elements and classes for a grid layout when you don't need to?

Comment: @FluffyKitten : Thanks for your response. Actually right now my purpose is to learn CSS grid out of interest. I have heard that many things can be accomplished by float,flexbox etc, but since I am new, I don't want to learn too many things, I just want to learn CSS Grid so well that I can accomplish even basic things using this quickly. And using dropdown from bootstrap library was just a quick way to get dropdown code to learn CSS grid concept to apply on.

Comment: @Meen639 You have no code at all for grids and your question & code are for the Bootstrap dropdown, so that's what we answered :)  If you are having problems with CGG grids, then that's a new question because each question here is about one single problem. Make sure you include a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-exam) that has the code that you are asking about this time :)

Answer (score 1):

D you need such a result?

```css
.nav-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Bootstrap
    </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">
  <ul>
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="mydiv" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```